# Backlit keyboard is OFF after recovering from clamshell mode

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, display

My keyboard backlit is ON while I'm working with my Macbook Pro with an HDTV connected as external display. However if I close the lid to enter clamshell mode and then open the lid again, I notice that the keyboard backlit is OFF.

The only way to turn in on again is flash a light right to the Facetime camera.

I'm using OS X 10.9.2 on a mid-2012 Macbook Pro.

Comment: actually it should work opposite, the keyboard backlit should come when is dark ?

Comment: So your problem is the sensor in the Facetime camera. When you shine light in it, it works because you change from dark to light. Try cleaning the lens and do this http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964

Comment: Since you report the problem appearing with the opening the clamshell it is helpful to publish 20-30 lines on your console at that time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately problems with Maverics and the build in camera is well known and document.

You have a little bit a odd one, but using the [recommended procedure](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2090) to try to fix it could not harm.

Resetting the PRAM and SMC is also recommended.

As for your flash light experiment:

As you shine the light in to the camera the keyboard back light is triggered indicating your camera is alive but not doing so well. The light sensitivity is not set properly.